# Unable to install web3 js for windows10

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, nodejs, windows

I am trying to install web3 using command

> npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26

However, it is failing with error :

`verbose node v8.9.1
verbose npm  v4.6.1
 error code 128
 error Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true rev-list -n1 browserifyCompatible
 error fatal: ambiguous argument 'browserifyCompatible': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
 error Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
 error 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

**EDIT** 
After following a suggestion in this thread, npm got updated but the npm installed with node was still being used. SO fixed that using [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm). Now, the error is showing as :

`794 verbose stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE clone --depth=1 -q -b browserifyCompatible git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-3198c7e8 --config core.longpaths=true
794 verbose stack warning: templates not found in C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\pacote-git-template-tmp\git-clone-f63c9472
794 verbose stack warning: Could not find remote branch browserifyCompatible to clone.
794 verbose stack fatal: Remote branch browserifyCompatible not found in upstream origin`

*Versions* : npm@6.4.1, node@v10.12.0 , git version 2.19.1

Yarn gives similar error. I tried tracing npm logs, the error occurs while looking up for branch named "browserifyCompatible" for websocket dependency which seems a valid branch.

I've tried starting cmd with admin privileges and executing from git bash and reinstaling git, node, npm. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing a newer version of web3, otherwise update node, try yarn and I guess other things, if you had docker you should be able to install.

Comment: I tried  using `npm install --save web3` with no luck. Yarn spits out same error. I didn't try with docker though. I have updated the post with more details.

Comment: Also, I think web3 is at like web@1.0.0-beta.26

Another alternative would be to try installing a project with web3 as a dependency such as truffle box.

Comment: Sure, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of npm is out of date. Upgrading should be as simple as running `npm i -g npm`.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work though. Same error again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to reproduce this, but it seems to be an incompatibly between npm and git (npm is usually the culprit). Can you update git and see if that resolves the issue? Otherwise update your post to specify the OS and versions of node, npm, and git. Also, you could try yarn.

Comment: I tried updating git too with no success. Sure, I'll update the post with more details